# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, Import and Export Wizard to create local copy, need primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, import, primary-key

I need to make a local copy of our QA database to test out a few queries before committing.  I was able to create a local database / download and import the data from the QA to my local copy using the Import and Export Wizard, but none of the primary key & foreign key mappings came with it.

Is there a way to get those too?

Long story short is I need to delete and replace some of the QA data.  Colleague told me I would need to do a 'on delete cascade' for it work probably.  I was going to test out my script first on a local copy, but the local copy is missing all of the keys we have in our QA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a copy of a database with all its settings, you may want to use the Backup and Restore commands.